# Configuring https access on HP A5120 Switch

Tags: networking, ssl, https, switch, hp

I am trying to configure HTTPS management on a HP a5120 switch running Version 5.20.99, Release 2215 and not having much luck. I have followed the manual by creating an SSL policy first and then enabling the HTTPS server with the SSL policy:

```
ssl server-policy sslpol
ip https ssl-server-policy sslpol
ip https enable
```

When I try and log onto the switch with Google Chrome I get the following error:

```
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

When I look this up I have found references to errors due to TLS being used in SSL. I can find no way to specify the SSL version in the server policy.

The manual has a configuration example that uses MSCEP to retrieve a certificate but in Windows 2008 R2 that feature is only available in Enterprise and Datacentre editions which I don't have.

I have SSH configured and it is using a locally generated certificate so I'm not sure if I can use that but I'd like to if possible.

Has anybody been able to setup HTTPS management on HP A series switches without MSCEP?

Any and all help appreciated!

here is a copy of my config with the interfaces removed:

```
version 5.20.99, Release 2215
#
 sysname MYSYSNAME
#
 irf domain 10
 irf mac-address persistent timer
 irf auto-update enable
 undo irf link-delay
#
 domain default enable system
#
 telnet server enable
#
vlan 1
#
vlan 100
 description Management
#
radius scheme system
 primary authentication 127.0.0.1 1645
 primary accounting 127.0.0.1 1646
 user-name-format without-domain
#
domain system
 access-limit disable
 state active
 idle-cut disable
 self-service-url disable
#
user-group system
 group-attribute allow-guest
#
local-user admin
 password cipher 
 authorization-attribute level 3
 service-type ssh telnet terminal
 service-type web
#
 stp enable
#
ssl server-policy sslpol
 pki-domain MYDOMAIN
#
interface NULL0
#
interface Vlan-interface199
 ip address 192.168.199.140 255.255.255.0
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 poe enable
 stp edged-port enable
#
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/1/2
#
 dhcp-snooping
#
 ntp-service unicast-server 192.168.1.71
#
 ssh server enable
#
 ip https ssl-server-policy sslpol
 ip https enable
#
 load xml-configuration
#
user-interface aux 0 1
user-interface vty 0 15
authentication-mode scheme
```

Answer (score 1):

HP's [specification](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c00778577#A3) doesn't specify what version of SSL the management interface is using but Google Chrome disables SSL 2.0 by default. Try enabling all possible versions of SSL under Options - Under the Hood - Security - Manage Certificates and try again. Using wireshark could also verify if there is a SSL version mismatch.

Comment: I have tried enabling all versions of SSL in internet options and its the same... I don't think its the browser... its my switch configuration. Google chrome gives an error code whereas the others just say page cannot be displayed...